# How to create only part of queries in transaction with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I'm trying to create a script to import about 10m records to mysql database.

When I did a loop with single queries, import with 2000 records takes 20 minutes.

So I'm trying to do this with transactions. The problem is, in my loop there are some select queries that need to be trigger at once to get some values to create inserts. Last two queries (insert and update) could be in in transaction.

Something like this:

```
foreach($record as $rec) {

   //select sth
   //do sth with result

   //second select sth 
   //do sth with second result

   //prepare values from above results and $rec 

   // below part I'd like to do with transaction

   //insert with new record    
   //update table
}
```

I know this is little messy and not exact, but this function is more complicated, so I decided to put just a "draft" and I need just advice, not complete code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are for multiple statements that need to be treated as a single group that either entirely succeeds or entirely fails. It sounds like your issue has a lot more to do with performance than transactions. Unless there is a bit of information that you haven't included that involves groups of statements "which all must succeed at the same time", transactions are just a distraction.

There are a few ways to approach your problem depending on some things that aren't immediately obvious from your post. 
-If your data source for the 10M records is a table in the same database that you are going to populate with the new records (via the inserts and updates at the end of your loop) then you might be able to do everything through a single database query. SQL is very expressive and through joins and some of the built in functions (SUBSTR(), UPPER(), REVERSE(), CASE...END, et c.) you might be able to do everything you want. This would require reading up on SQL and trying to reframe your goals in terms of set operations that you could do.
-If you are inserting records that are sourced from outside the database (like from a file) then I would organize your code like this

```
//select sth
//do sth with result

//second select sth 
//do sth with second result

//prepare values from above results so that $rec info can be added in later

foreach($record as $rec) {
   //construct a big insert statement
}

//insert the new records by running the big insert statement   
//update table
```

The advantage here is that you are only hitting the db with a few queries, instead of a few queries per $rec so your performance will be better (since db calls have overhead). For 10M rows you may need to break the above up into a few chunks since there is a limit to how big a single insert can be (see  max_allowed_packet). I would suggest breaking the 10M into 5K or 10K chunks by adding another loop around the above that partitions off the chunks from the 10M.

A clearer answer could have been given if you added details about your data source, what transformations you want to do on the data, what the purpose of the

```
   //select sth
   //do sth with result

   //second select sth 
   //do sth with second result
```

section is (within the context of how it adds information to your insert statements later), and what the prepare values section of your code does.